# Use of undefined constant MCRYPT_BLOWFISH - assumed 'MCRYPT_BLOWFISH'

Tags: php, magento, ampps

I'm using Magento 2. Installed a theme and I want to upgrade my system. (And I'm using AMPPS on Mac)

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

When I command these line in Terminal, get this **error:**

> [ErrorException]
>         Use of undefined constant MCRYPT_BLOWFISH - assumed 'MCRYPT_BLOWFISH'

How can I debug and solve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

`MCRYPT_BLOWFISH` is a PHP constant.  This constant is defined by the [mycrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php) extension.  If your version of PHP has mcrypt installed, this constant is present.  The error message you're seeing

> Use of undefined constant MCRYPT_BLOWFISH - assumed 'MCRYPT_BLOWFISH'

is telling you that this constant is **not** present.  That means mycrypt is not installed or enabled for the version of PHP you're running.  You need to install or enable mcrypt.

Some gotchas.

- The version of PHP you're running on the command line may be different from the version of PHP you're using for Apache/nginx.  `$ which php`, `$ php -v`, and `php --info` can tell you what's available for your CLI PHP
- You may have the extension installed, but disabled via a `php.ini` file.  You can find which `php.ini` files you're using in the `--info` call above, by running a small program that calls `phpinfo()`, or with `$ php --ini`

Answer (score 1):

- if you are using the PHP 7.1 then run the below command will resolve your mcrypt issue.

**sudo apt-get install php7.1-mcrypt**

change the php version as per your system, I hope it will help.
after installing it do not forget to restart the apache server

if it help mark this as an answer

Answer (score -2):

REINDEX SOLVED PROBLEM MAGENTO 2 ON AMPPS after check mcrypt on extension from AMPPS (AMPPS->PHP->PHP Extension), on OSX :

I typed:

```
cd /Applications/AMPPS/www/magento/bin/

php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

and I diplayed the following error:

> [Exception]
>   Notice: Use of undefined constant MCRYPT_BLOWFISH - assumed
>   'MCRYPT_BLOWFISH'in/Applications/AMPPS/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Encryption/E
>   ncryptor.php on line 397

I solved as follows:

from command line and from home:

```
sudo vi .bash_profile
```

insert the line: `export PATH="/Applications/AMPPS/php-5.6/bin:$PATH"`
with the php version used by AMPPS and reboot the command line, in this way magento will use the right PHP version to lunch reindex:

```
cd /Applications/AMPPS/www/magento/bin/

php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

If you would lunch reindex without going to `/Applications/AMPPS/www/magento/bin/` you could add in `.bash_profile`, another line as follows:

opening `.bash_profile` from home:

```
vi bash_profile
```

inserting the line:

```
export PATH="/Applications/AMPPS/www/magento/bin:$PATH"
```

and then reboot the terminal lunching only the command:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Comment: Please post in English only

Comment: dont use french here